# How can I set the minimum window size of my Flutter app on iPadOS?

Tags: flutter, ipad

With Stage Manager on iPadOS the user can resize the app window to a certain degree. The smallest I can do with the Flutter demo app is about 20% of the horizontal screen size and 60% vertical size (in a floating window). Is it possible to allow even smaller sizes or to somehow influence this behaviour in general?